# How to submit new address using curl

Tags: here-api

Hi i am trying to add new address using curl API

[here-API example link](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/map_feedback/incorrect-address-feedback)

I used to this blog example but it showing 540 gateway timeout

body:::

[{
  "type":"Point",
  "coordinates":[-87.63245,41.88425],
  "properties": {
    "v": "2.7",
    "referenceIds" : ["276397653"],
    "details": "Update of phone number, URL and e-mail",
    "phone": "+1 111 2 333",
    "email": "MyPlace@MyPlace.com",
    "URL":  "www.MyPlace.com",
    "error": 31,
    "currentValues": {
       "phone": "+1 111 2 350"
    },
    "appId": "hIY6TtmGIDrjdjayDWYn"
  }
}]

headers:::

[{"key":"Auth-Service-Id","value":"here_app","description":""},{"key":"Auth-Identifier","value":"hIY6TtmGIDrjdjayDWYn","description":""},{"key":"Auth-Secret","value":"3zKE2v6wpZ51p7Xi4WC2Fg","description":""},{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/vnd.here.layerObjectList+json; charset=UTF-8","description":""},{"key":"Group-Id","value":"FGx1AWaAzKOo0imNkLmf","description":""},{"key":"Content-Disposition","value":"application/vnd.here.layerObjectList+json; charset=UTF-8","description":""},{"key":"Accept","value":"application/vnd.here.layerObjectList+json","description":""},{"key":"Accept-Charset","value":"charset=UTF-8","description":""}]

Comment: Please provide the code and data you were trying to post so that we can serve you better.

Comment: We tried the same example you have provided and got 200 response. Please check your app id and code values.

Comment: can i have example code which your trying.my appid and secret i sent in that onlyApp ID
hIY6TtmGIDrjdjayDWYn
App Code
3zKE2v6wpZ51p7Xi4WC2Fg please can you give answer i will check same in post man

Comment: and we are using present free account just for implementing purpose pls get address is done adding is pending so pls hel in that we are iimplementing php code

Answer (score 0):

Below are the header and body values passed in postman: 
[image: Header]

[image: Body]

[image: Response]

Comment: if i want post post using php url  https://maphub.cit.api.here.com/feedback/ this is url is i need to hit right

Comment: Yes its the same.

Comment: body Format is you mentioned text but it is json right

Comment: what i need is exactly i need how add headers  and body in php